# Как настроить .htaccess для автоперевода сайта на https?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

Добавил на сайт SSL-сертификат. Теперь нужно, чтобы любое обращение к сайту по http: автоматически переводилось на https:

Подскажите каким образом нужно изменить такой .htaccess, чтобы получить нужное поведение:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /    

# RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^test/(x.+/)?$ index.php?page=test [L]
RewriteRule ^test/create/((de|es)/)?$ index.php?page=create&lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/create/(([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/)?$ index.php?page=create&token=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=test&act=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/replay/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/$ index.php?page=test&replay=$1 [L]
```

только изменение строки:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

на:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

дает желаемое поведение не во всех случаях.

UPD: обновил .htaccess до варианта 9 из ответа @Alex:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=404

RewriteEngine On

# https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/apache/#http2https

RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/apache/#redirect

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

# старый вариант переадресации на www.
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.ru
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

# RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^test/(x.+/)?$ index.php?page=test [L]
RewriteRule ^test/create/((de|es)/)?$ index.php?page=create&lang=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/create/(([0-9A-Fa-f]+)/)?$ index.php?page=create&token=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/$ index.php?page=test&act=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^test/replay/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/$ index.php?page=test&replay=$1 [L]
```

... работает.

Comment: "дает желаемое поведение не во всех случаях" - а в каких именно не дает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё зависит от настроек хостера, **поэтому в первую очередь рекомендую посмотреть faq хостера**, это избавит вас от множества вопросов и сохранит уйму времени.

Приведу ниже несколько вариантов. Желательно писать сразу после директивы

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Вариант 1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Вариант 2

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Вариант 3

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Вариант 4

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Вариант 5

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Вариант 6

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Вариант 7

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Вариант 8

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.сайт.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Вариант 9

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: хостинг - .masterhost

Comment: добавил вариант 9. взят с вашего хостера https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/apache/ пункт "Переадресация с HTTP на HTTPS при использовании IP+SSL"

Comment: только скорее всего вместо [L,R] нужно [L,R=301]

Comment: спасибо за ответ, вроде работает. я, честно говоря, думал, что есть единственный вариант, который будет работать везде. ну, может, с небольшими ньюансами ...

Comment: спасибо желательно выразить через птичку - правильный ответ и награду в конкурсе )

Comment: я не очень в теме .htaccess... [L], как я понял, означает LAST, чтобы прекратить выполнение дальнейших правил по списку ниже, но следующее правило - редирект на www все равно выполняется (так и нужно, чтобы оно выполнялось), почему?

Comment: [L,R=301] - значит прекратить выполнения правил, т.е. не выполнять, то что ниже. и отдать ответ 301. После этого страницы загружается уже по протоколу HTTPS, поэтому правило RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$ не срабатывает и тогда срабатывает проверка на www. она также делает редирект...  т.е. фактически у вас 2 редиректа.... вы можете сделать вторую строку как в варианте 8, тогда сразу будет правильный редирект

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.somedomain.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: заменил две строки после RewriteEngine On на четыре вышеприведенных - результат такой: https://ibb.co/1TFCBBy